# Android アプリで、特定の端末でのみ RecyclerView から遷移した Activity がメモリリークしてしまいますが原因がわかりません

Tags: java, android, メモリ管理

開発中のアプリで RecyclerView のリストから、ある Activity に遷移し再び RecyclerView に戻ると、常に LeakCanary で遷移先 Activity のメモリリークが検出されます。

手元に端末が3種類あるのですが、 リークが起こるのは
AQUOS sense6s (Android13)
のみで、
AQUOS sense3 (Android11) と LG AndroidOne X5 (Android11)
では発生しないようです。

また、試しに android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 指定してアプリ起動後に直接 Activity を開いた場合は発生しないようです。

そもそもリークの発生源である com.qualcomm.qti.Performance クラスとは何なのでしょうか？
検索しても情報がほとんどなく困っています。

もしわかる方いらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願いいたします。

以下リークする Activity です。

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test); // 空のレイアウト
    }
}
```

RecyclerView のアダプタクラス

```
public class LeadSheetListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LeadSheetListViewHolder> {

    private List<LeadSheet> list;

    /*public ProgressionListAdapter(List<ProgressionRowData> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }*/

    public LeadSheetListAdapter() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setList(List<LeadSheet> list) {
        this.list = list;
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "setList() list.size:" + list.size());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public LeadSheetListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View inflate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_leadsheet_list, parent,false);
        LeadSheetListViewHolder vh = new LeadSheetListViewHolder(inflate);
        return vh;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LeadSheetListViewHolder holder, int position) {

        LeadSheet sheet = list.get(position);
        holder.titleView.setText(sheet.getTitle());
        String description = "";
        long id = sheet.getLeadSheetId();
        int numOfMeasures = sheet.getMeasures().size();
        description += numOfMeasures + "小節" + " id:" + id;
        holder.summaryView.setText(description);

        if (sheet.getTags().size() > 0) {
            for (String tag : sheet.getTags()) {
                TextView tagView = new TextView(holder.tagsContainer.getContext());
                tagView.setText("#" + tag);
                holder.tagsContainer.addView(tagView);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tagView.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.rightMargin = 20;
            }
            holder.tagsContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.tagsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.rowBody.setId(holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
        holder.rowBody.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            v.setBackgroundColor(v.getResources().getColor(R.color.theme1_selection_bg));

            // TestActivity に遷移
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, TestActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("leadsheetId", sheet.leadSheetId);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        });

        holder.rowBody.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
            Context vContext = v.getContext();
            v.setBackgroundColor(v.getResources().getColor(R.color.theme1_selection_bg));

            String[] choices = {"削除", "タグを編集"};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(vContext);
            builder.setTitle("操作を選択")
                    .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", (dialog, i) -> dialog.dismiss())
                    .setItems(choices, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if (which == 0) {
                                // リードシートを削除
                                showDeleteConfirmationDialog(vContext, v, sheet);
                            } else if (which == 1) {
                                // タグを追加
                                showEditTagsDialog(vContext, v, sheet);
                            }
                        }

                    });
            builder.create().show();
            return true;
        });
    }

    private void showDeleteConfirmationDialog(Context context, View v, LeadSheet sheet) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Delete This Item?")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                    String name = sheet.getTitle();
                    BaseApplication.getRepository().deleteLeadSheet(sheet);
                    notifyItemRemoved(v.getId());
                    Snackbar.make(v, name + "を削除しました", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("復元不可", null).show();
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", (dialog, i) -> dialog.dismiss())
                .show();
    }

    private void showEditTagsDialog(Context context, View v, LeadSheet leadSheet) {
        EditText editText = new EditText(context);
        String text = "";
        for (String tag : leadSheet.getTags()) {
            text += tag + " ";
        }
        text = text.trim();
        text = text.replaceAll("\\s+", ", ");
        editText.setText(text);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("タグを追加")
                .setMessage("タグを入力してください (コンマ区切りで複数入力可)")
                .setView(editText)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                            String string = editText.getText().toString();
                            String[] tags = string.split(",\\s*");
                            leadSheet.tags = Arrays.asList(tags);
                            BaseApplication.getRepository().saveLeadSheet(leadSheet);
                            notifyItemChanged(v.getId());
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", (dialog, i) -> dialog.dismiss())
                .show();
    }

    // DEBUG
    private void test(Context context, LeadSheet sheet, int viewId) {
        Log.d(context.getClass().getSimpleName(), "run() leadSheet");
        for (Measure measure : sheet.getMeasures()) {
            for (ChordNotation notation : measure.getNotationsByBeat()) {
                Log.d(context.getClass().getSimpleName(), "run() notation.getClass:" + notation.getClass().getSimpleName());
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(sheet.getTitle()) + " listId:" + viewId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (list == null) {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "getItemCount() list = null");
            return 0;
        } else {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "getItemCount() list.size:" + list.size());
            return list.size();
        }
    }

}
```

LeakCanary のログ

```
====================================
HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
====================================
1 APPLICATION LEAKS
References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.
104704 bytes retained by leaking objects
Signature: 1f48c2e3c9d42514de20b1df25c05a32d67be916
┬───
│ GC Root: System class
│
├─ com.qualcomm.qti.Performance class
│    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
│    ↓ static Performance.mContext
│                         ~~~~~~~~
├─ androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper instance
│    Leaking: YES (ContextThemeWrapper wraps an Activity with Activity.mDestroyed true)
│    Retaining 104.7 kB in 1347 objects
│    mBase instance of com.example.XXXXXXXX.ui.leadsheetedit.view.TestActivity with mDestroyed
│    = true
│    ↓ ContextWrapper.mBase
╰→ com.example.XXXXXXXX.ui.leadsheetedit.view.TestActivity instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.example.XXXXXXXX.ui.
​     leadsheetedit.view.TestActivity received Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
​     Retaining 6.5 kB in 234 objects
​     key = ed3b1035-b5f0-4182-bf15-8adf3cc3ed18
​     watchDurationMillis = 11978
​     retainedDurationMillis = 6977
​     mApplication instance of com.example.XXXXXXXX.BaseApplication
​     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper
====================================
0 LIBRARY LEAKS
A Library Leak is a leak caused by a known bug in 3rd party code that you do not have control over.
See https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals-how-leakcanary-works/#4-categorizing-leaks
====================================
0 UNREACHABLE OBJECTS
An unreachable object is still in memory but LeakCanary could not find a strong reference path
from GC roots.
====================================
METADATA
Please include this in bug reports and Stack Overflow questions.
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: 33
Build.MANUFACTURER: SHARP
LeakCanary version: 2.9.1
App process name: com.example.XXXXXXXX
Class count: 25155
Instance count: 220093
Primitive array count: 137883
Object array count: 32014
Thread count: 28
Heap total bytes: 27453955
Bitmap count: 3
Bitmap total bytes: 77115
Large bitmap count: 0
Large bitmap total bytes: 0
Db 1: open /data/user/0/com.example.XXXXXXXX/databases/chordist.db
Db 2: open /data/user/0/com.example.XXXXXXXX/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db
Db 3: open /data/user/0/com.example.XXXXXXXX/no_backup/androidx.work.workdb
Stats: LruCache[maxSize=3000,hits=118135,misses=221893,hitRate=34%]
RandomAccess[bytes=11122379,reads=221893,travel=66942137287,range=33184478,size=41032206]
Heap dump reason: 4 retained objects, app is not visible
Analysis duration: 60178 ms
Heap dump file path: /storage/emulated/0/Download/leakcanary-com.example.
chordsoundcreationandplayingtest/2023-07-08_05-59-02_824.hprof
Heap dump timestamp: 1688763616723
Heap dump duration: 6054 ms
====================================
```

こちらは遷移先 Activity から戻るボタンで RecyclerView に戻った時に出力されるログです

```
2023-07-08 14:08:49.959 22593-22593 LeakCanary              com...XXXXXXXXD  Watching instance of androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerViewModel (androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerViewModel received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 3c19f428-c811-436e-9d2b-b9e4e0ed2f85
2023-07-08 14:08:49.959 22593-22593 LeakCanary              com...XXXXXXXXD  Watching instance of androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandlesVM (androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandlesVM received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key 521a4f1b-8e7e-44a4-b15b-6d4b730ef911
2023-07-08 14:08:49.960 22593-22593 LeakCanary              com...XXXXXXXXD  Watching instance of leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher (leakcanary.internal.ViewModelClearedWatcher received ViewModel#onCleared() callback) with key e8357ad8-3f8e-4077-9970-7dec19b9c8ea
2023-07-08 14:08:49.960 22593-22593 LeakCanary              com...XXXXXXXXD  Watching instance of androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment (androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment received Fragment#onDestroy() callback) with key 7db6d49a-969b-423e-9e91-ad2878d30d09
2023-07-08 14:08:49.960 22593-22593 LeakCanary              com...XXXXXXXXD  Watching instance of com.example.XXXXXXXX.ui.leadsheetedit.view.TestActivity (com.example.XXXXXXXX.ui.leadsheetedit.view.TestActivity received Activity#onDestroy() callback) with key 5116d3bc-5f30-4ee3-b428-33e54626ae7c
```

build.gradle(:app)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.XXXXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    /* Using native library */
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0-alpha05'

    /* MidiDriver */
    implementation project(path: ':MidiDriver-1.1')
    /* Gson */
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    /* UI */
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'
    /* ViewModel */
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.5.1'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.5.1"
    /* Room */
    def room_version = "2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"
    /* DataStore */
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-rxjava2:1.0.0"
    /* ad */
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation project(':nativetemplates')
    /* test */
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    /* debug */
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.9.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

遷移先の Activity の継承を AppCompatActivity から FragmentActivity に変更したところメモリリークが発生しなくなりました。原因は全く分かりませんが、とりあえず解決できました。

変更前
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity
↓
変更後
public class TestActivity extends FragmentActivity

依存関係が原因の可能性もあるため、gradle(:app) も追記しました。
同じ様な症状ある方はご参考にしてください。